# In web.config how do I redirect based on ONLY one URL parameter

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I need a redirect rule for my web.config file which uses the ID URL parameter ONLY, ignoring all other parameters.

Example:

https://example.com/photos.php?id=12345&s=static&x=123

Should redirect to:

https://example.com/photos/12345/

Currently https://example.com/photos.php?id=12345  will redirect, but the example above, with trailing parameters, will not.

Here are my current redirect and rewrite rules:

```
<rule name="Photos Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^photos\.php$" />
   <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
      <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^id=([0-9]*)$" />
      <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="photos/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>

<rule name="Photos Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^photos/([^/]+)/?$" />
   <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Rewrite" url="photos.php?id={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Much appreciated.

Comment: So, remove the `$`.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your rewrite rule, and tried to modify it, but still couldn't achieve redirect based on ONLY one URL parameter.

So I wrote a new rewrite rule referring to this case: https://serverfault.com/questions/372991/iis-url-rewrite-module-query-string-parameters.

```
               <rule name="Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="id=([^&amp;]+)" />                 
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="/photo/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
                </rule>
```

After my test, when requesting **localhost/photo.aspx?id=123&x=asd&c=111** or other urls containing multiple querystring values on my site, it can be redirected to **localhost:/photo/123**. Hope it works for you.